# JavaScript setTimeout based on input

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog, settimeout

I am creating a widget to display information on a slideshow. Once a user interacts with an item, a PDF comes up. I am attempting to create an alert that would come up if the display has not been interacted with for about 15 seconds. I have the functions working perfectly, but coming across a problem... I have the following code:

```
    function alertQuestion(){
      alertModal.style.display = "block";
      var resumeSlideshow = setTimeout(closeAndPlaySlideshow,8000);
    }
    yesButton.onclick = function(){
      alertModal.style.display = "none";
      clearTimeout(resumeSlideshow);
      setTimeout(alertQuestion,10000);
      present = true
    }
    noButton.onclick = function(){
      alertModal.style.display = "none";
      modal.style.display = "none";
      modal2.style.display = "none";
      modal3.style.display = "none";
      modalOpen = false;
      clearTimeout(resumeSlideshow);
      clearInterval(slideInterval);
      playSlideshow();
    }
```

As stated, the "alertQuestion()" function comes up after the display is left idle for a little bit. The alert modal contains two questions "Yes" and "No". The buttons work as they should. I have a "setTimeout" method set once the alert modal comes up to start a timer and to close everything and resume the slideshow if there is no reply inputed. However, the problem I am having is that even if a user clicks "Yes", I can not get the "resumeSlideshow" timeout to clear. I want the inputs to be taken under consideration, so the timeout can start over again from 0. As of now, the user can click "Yes" to stay and read, but the "resumeSlideshow" method will carry on and cancel out of everything. Any modifications and tips would be helpful.

Comment: My guess is scope. If you `console.log(resumeSlideshow);` inside of yesbutton.onclick, I bet it's undefined. You'll possibly have to attach the setTimeout to a global or use your own events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable doesnt exist outside of the context of your function. You need to move it outside

```
var resumeSlideshow;
function alertQuestion(){
  alertModal.style.display = "block";
  resumeSlideshow = setTimeout(closeAndPlaySlideshow,8000);
}
```